CloudKit CKQuery Predicate to find next available name
I'm attempting to query the CloudKit database for the following -
(Example)
userName = "Fred"
Let's say that this is unavailable (checked with a query), so I want to find names which begin with "Fred" and end in digits, eg, "Fred1", "Fred12", "Fred126", etc, so I can suggest the next available "Fred" option. Since it doesn't seem possible to use a MATCHES query with a regex in CloudKit, is there an alternative? It would seem ludicrous to have to fire off 10 separate queries like so -
NSPredicate(format: "userName BEGINSWITH %@", "Fred0")
NSPredicate(format: "userName BEGINSWITH %@", "Fred1")
etc

Plus it's not reliable, eg, if there's a name such as "Fred12Smith".
If anyone has any idea how to solve this, I'd be very grateful.

You only have to search once, as;
   NSPredicate(format: "userName BEGINSWITH %@", "Fred")

Then process the result set yourself to see the next free Fred. The result set will contain all the Freds.

Unfortunately this doesn’t work as it will also return all “Freddy” items too, which means that to find the “Fred” with the highest number appended (eg, “Fred4367”) becomes a process of pulling a potentially huge amount of data & filtering it
